# "Take me through the mud"

Tags: idioms

I heard this phrase:

> Take me through the mud, but don't drag my family through it.

I wonder what it means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Dragging someone through the mud implies attacking their character and motivations, or accusing them of wrong-doing. Mud is a metaphor for evil or wrong-doing. A related term is mud-slinging, which would be throwing mud at someone.

Depending on the exact quote and the context, the speaker could be saying that his accusers can accuse him of anything, but that they should refrain from accusing his family. Or the speaker might be asking that accusations be made in private and not in public where his family would have to hear about it and would also be tarnished by it.

This sounds like a quote of a politician who is basically saying that politics is dirty and (false or exaggerated) accusations are often made, but politicians' families should not be dragged into the fighting.